# Extract 50% and 95% utilisation distribution from raster (and plot in ggplot)

Tags: raster, kernel-density, ggplot

I have a list of rasters, each holding a kernel density estimation with utilization distribution from animals. The cells within each raster add up to 1. I want to extract the 50% and the 95% utilisation distribution from these rastsers, convert them to a polygon, and then plot them in ggplot.

dummy data for 1 raster:

```
# Create a raster with 1000 cells and values that sum up to 1 (similar to your previous example)
rows <- 50
cols <- 20
n_cells <- rows * cols
r <- raster(matrix(0, nrow = rows, ncol = cols))
random_values <- runif(n_cells)
random_values <- random_values / sum(random_values)
values(r) <- random_values
```

Dummy data for list or rasters

```
# Create a function to generate a dummy raster with values that add up to 1
generate_dummy_raster <- function() {
  r <- raster(matrix(0, nrow = rows, ncol = cols))
  random_values <- runif(n_cells)
  random_values <- random_values / sum(random_values)
  values(r) <- random_values
  return(r)
}

# Create a list of dummy rasters
num_rasters <- 5  # Change this to the desired number of rasters
dummy_raster_list <- lapply(1:num_rasters, function(i) generate_dummy_raster())

# Print the values of each raster and their sum
for (i in 1:num_rasters) {
  cat("Raster", i, "values:", values(dummy_raster_list[[i]]), "\n")
  cat("Raster", i, "sum:", sum(values(dummy_raster_list[[i]])), "\n\n")
}
```